# Showing formally that $U = \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} U_{j}$ produces a topology $U \subset \mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

In the text "Functions of One Complex Varible" i'm having trouble showing how $U_{j}$ forms a topology $U$ in $(1)$

$(1)$

Let $U_{1} \subset U_{2} \subset U_{3} \subset \cdot \cdot \cdot \subset \mathbb{C}$ be connected open sets and define: 
$$U = \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} U_{j}$$

Let $f$ be a holomrphic function on $U$ Suppose that, for each $j$, $f\vert_{U_{j}}$ has a holomorphic antiderivative on $U_{j}$. Prove then that $f$ has a holomorphic antiderative on all of $U$.

$(2)$

$$\text{Lemma}$$

Before one can formally notion that $f$ has a holomorphic antiderative  on all of $U$.$U_{j}$ must form a topology  denoted by $U$. The formal notions of a topology within $\mathbb{C}$ is developed in $(2.1)$.

$(2.1)$

A $\text{topology}$ on a nonempty set $X$ is a collection of subsets of $T$ of subsets $X$ is a topology on $X$ if:

$$\text{(a)} \, \, \, \, \, \phi, \text{X} \in T \, ; \, $$

$$\text{(b)}\, \, \, \,  \, \text{If} \, \,  G_{a} \in T \, \text{for} \, a \in \text{A}, \text{then} \bigcup_{a \in A}G_{a} \in \text{T}$$

$$\text{(c)}\, \, \,  \text{If} \,  G_{i} \, \in T \, \text{for} \, I = 1,2...,n, \text{then} \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} G_{i} \in T$$

The recent yet axiomatic developments on $(2.1)$ I'm having trouble applying is there another way to show $U = \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} U_{j}$ "produces" a topological space $U$. I'd like a hint no full answers please.

Comment: My confusion mainly lies within the following conditions $(b)$ and $(c)$, I could not discern what $G_{a}$ and $G_{I}$ were

Comment: $A$ is some arbitrarily large indexing set and for each $a\in A$ we have an open set $G_a\in T$. So $(b)$ is saying your topology is closed under arbitrary unions and $(c)$ is saying your topology is closed under finite intersections.

Comment: Ahhh ok thank you also is my approach to proving $(1)$ correct, I feel like setting up the "Topology" where $f(z)$ is a little too much.

Comment: A topology is a collection of subsets so $\Psi \not \subset \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Well yeah, our topology would be $U$, I'll have reedit that in my post sorry for the mistake. i'll have to rewrite and redefine somethings.

Comment: You are confusing $U = \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} U_{j}$ and $\{U_{j}|j \in \mathbb{N}\}$. The first is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, the second a collection of subsets of $U$, which is the first requirement for a topology on $U$. If you check the other conditions you quote, you'll find them all satisfied except (a) and some cases of (b). Add in  $\emptyset$ and $U$ and you'll have a topology.

Comment: Ahhh ok so I was on the right on the track sorry I got confused I just didn't know how $U$ would satisfy the last conditions sorry when I saw @JonathanDavidson comment on  $\Psi \not \subset \mathbb{C}$ I thought I made a huge mistake and second-guessed myself sorry :(.

Comment: Why do you believe the empty set is one of the $U_i$?  Or are you thinking that the topology you're interested in is given by the subbasis $\{U_i\}_i$?

Comment: I actually didn't know what would be the empty set since the union of the sets are non-empty, so one would have to create a empty set within $U$, and I wasn't sure if it was kosher to introduce another set within our Topology $U$ that was non-empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ does not have a holomorphic antiderivative on $U$.  Then (since you asked only for a hint) "something bad happens on a compact set, $K$, contained in $U$".  Since $K$ is in $U$ and is compact, there is a finite collection of indices $I'$ such that $C = \{U_i : i \in I'\}$ is a finite open cover of $K$.  But $\max I'$ exists, so f does not have a holomorphic antiderivative on $U_{\max I'}$, a contradiction.  (I have skipped saying why $K \subset U_{\max I'}$, but you should not.)

This is frequently the sort of argument to look for when working with the union of an ascending chain.

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by $U_{\max I'}$, and sorry for the dumb question there's so many equivalent definitions of a Topology some easier to apply then others :(, and happen to get a hard definition.

Comment: @Zophikel : You have a nested sequence, $(U_i)_{i \in I}$.  $I'$ is a finite subset of $I$, so there is a maximum element of $I'$, $\max I'$.  $U_{\max I'}$ is therefore the "last" element of the sequence needed to cover $K$.  (Later elements cover $K$, but you don't need them.)

Comment: Also can you clarify the notion:"something bad happens on a compact set, 
$K$, contained in $U$.

Comment: @Zophikel : Not and remain in compliance with "I'd like a hint no full answers please.".

Comment: @Zophikel : I suppose the smallest possible hint in this direction is : Morera's Theorem.  But literally, to say more completes the proof.

Comment: ahhh, ok I actually considered this I'll have to dive through your hint in more detail, also looking back at my original approach it could be easier to attack the question directly. Thanks for the @Eric Towers and i'm sorry for my incompetence.